# Why doesn't the prompt on my Git Bash for Windows appear?

Tags: windows, git, bash, prompt

All of a sudden, the prompt doesn't appear when opening Git Bash for Windows:

[image: promptless bash]

It was working fine before.
When I close the window, it gives me this:

[image: error on close]

I am using Windows 10 (64 bit).
I just uninstalled the old Git and re-installed the latest version 2.13.3 but the problem remains the same. Also, I checked and the same bash used for the terminal inside my editors like Visual Studio Code or Atom works fine.

Does anybody have similar experience like this? What can cause this?

The last thing I remember before this problem occurred was that I installed the Dropbox desktop app.

Answer (score 0):

It got resolved today.

It was a big pause with no prompt for sometime then message appeared that key has been added (I have SSH keys and `ssh-agent` added for GitHub). Then prompt appeared and working normally now.

Not sure if it has something to do with `ssh-agent` being hanged for a moment.

Thanks anyway!